# df.diff() how to compare row A with last row B

Tags: pandas

If we have two columns A and B
how to compare row A with last row B

```
   A         B            diff
0  0.904560  0.208318     0
1  0.679290  0.747496     0
2  0.069841  0.165834     0
3  0.045818  0.907888     0
4  0.485712  0.593785     0
5  0.771665  0.800182     0
6  0.485041  0.024829     0
7  0.897172  0.584406     0
8  0.561953  0.626699     0
9  0.412803  0.900643     0
```

Comment: Please add your expected output

Comment: df['diff']=df['A']-df['B']?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pandas' `shift` function to create a 'lagged' version of column B. Then it's a simple difference between columns.

```
from io import StringIO 
import pandas as pd

raw = '''
A,B
0.904560,0.208318
0.679290,0.747496
0.069841,0.165834
0.045818,0.907888
0.485712,0.593785
0.771665,0.800182
0.485041,0.024829
0.897172,0.584406
0.561953,0.626699
0.412803,0.900643
'''.strip()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw))
df['B_lag'] = df.B.shift(1)
df['diff'] = df.A - df.B_lag

print(df)
```

Output looks like

```
          A         B     B_lag      diff
0  0.904560  0.208318       NaN       NaN
1  0.679290  0.747496  0.208318  0.470972
2  0.069841  0.165834  0.747496 -0.677655
3  0.045818  0.907888  0.165834 -0.120016
4  0.485712  0.593785  0.907888 -0.422176
5  0.771665  0.800182  0.593785  0.177880
6  0.485041  0.024829  0.800182 -0.315141
7  0.897172  0.584406  0.024829  0.872343
8  0.561953  0.626699  0.584406 -0.022453
9  0.412803  0.900643  0.626699 -0.213896
```